# Doctrine isn't working After version upgrade

Tags: php, annotations, doctrine-orm

I do generate entities from database. Here is a file that I generated before updating to new version of doctrine and with the latest version of doctrine:

http://pastebin.com/g8DsUjmm

You will see, it adds an extra 'ORM' in annotations on new ones.

I am now having problem(Exception) while executing doctrine code which says:

> Class GdCities does not exist and could not be loaded /my_path/application/third_party/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/RuntimeReflectionService.php

Anyone have any idea, why this is happening. before updating, with old entities and doctrine version, it was working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did get this resolved by removing the "ORM\" part from all entities' table and column name. Not sure, if its a doctrine bug or I am doing something in different way.